# When may the Kernel Trick Matrix be non symmetric?

Tags: predictive-models, matrix, kernel-trick, train, symmetry

Ridge Regression can be expressed as $$\hat{y} = (\mathbf{X'X} + a\mathbf{I}_d)^{-1}\mathbf{X}x$$ where $\hat{y}$ is the predicted label, $\mathbf{I}_d$ the $d \times d$ identify matrix, $\mathbf{x}$ the object we're trying to find a label for, and $\mathbf{X}$ the $n \times d$ matrix of $n$ objects $\mathbf{x}_i = (x_{i,1}, ..., x_{i,d})\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that:

$$
\mathbf{X} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1,1} &  x_{1,2} & \ldots & x_{1,d}\\
x_{2,1} &  x_{2,2} & \ldots & x_{2,d}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{n,1}  & x_{1,2} &\ldots & x_{n,d}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can kernelise this as follows: $$\hat{y} = (\mathbf{\mathcal{K}} + a\mathbf{I}_d)^{-1} \mathbf{k}$$

where $\mathbf{\mathcal{K}}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of kernel functions $K$

$$\mathcal{K} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
K(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_1) &  K(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2) & \ldots & K(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_n)\\
K(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}_1) & K(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}_2) & \ldots & K(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}_n)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
K(\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{x}_1) & K(\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{x}_2) &\ldots & K(\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{x}_n)
\end{pmatrix} $$

and $\mathbf{k}$ the $n \times 1$ column vector of kernel functions $K$

$$\mathbf{k} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
K(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x})\\
K(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}) \\
\vdots \\
K(\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{x}) 
\end{pmatrix}$$

What about the case where the training data, $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{40}$ and $\textbf{y}$ is the test data $\in \mathbb{R}^{10}$?

But the Kernel, $\mathcal{K}$ loses its symmetry matrix?
Does this make sense? You take the dot product between training and test data and do not have a a square matrix.

Comment: It is not. The kernel must be symmetric to learn the coefficients, but the functional form of the prediction doesn't require a symmetric K

Comment: If you had 40 training points, and 10 test points, how do you even define the kernel?

Comment: A 40x10 matrix.

Comment: When you do gradient descent, the train and test sizes aren't equal, so you can't learn the coefficients, with unequal train and test sizes?

Comment: You learn coefficients using only the train data (so a 40x40 matrix in you example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During training, the kernel trick matrix is symmetric.

During prediction, the kernel trick matrix is a rectangle. # Columns in prediction kernel trick matrix equals test samples. # Rows equals samples during training.